# AJAX response being returned to browser without error but not displaying

Tags: html, ajax

The following rendered HTML

```
<div class='cell small-2' id='fulfillment_form_452'>
  <form ...
</div>
```

has a form which is submitted, properly PATCHed and processed by the application and the browser debugger consistently returns a 200 message  with a response that appears proper:

```
$("#fulfillment_form_452").html("  1\n<span style=\'float: right;\'>1.25&nbsp;$<\/span>\n");
```

However that form is not being replaced by the HTML snippet.

Note: there are multiple `id`s on the page `fulfillment_form_446`  `fulfillment_form_431`, etc.

What could explain theblock not being refreshed & how could this be debugged?

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that in this instance the javascript response had to be generated as

```
$("div#fulfillment_form_452").html[...]
```

Possible explanation: as the HTML content had a span tag while the origin has a div tag with the identifier?